# How does compiler determine which function to use?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, operator-overloading

As we know compiler determines the function by the overloaded function signature (like parameter types), but how does this one work:

```
v[i] = 1;
```

When compiler looks at these two overloaded functions:

```
const T& operator[](size_t i) const;
T& operator[](size_t i);
```

How does it determine which one to use? Does the compiler tries to use 1st one, and finds out it does not work, then it tries to use the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the object is non-const, the non-const version of the function is invoked (if it is available), else const version is invoked. Now see which is which:

```
const T& operator[](size_t i) const;   //CONST MEMBER FUNCTION
T& operator[](size_t i);               //NON-CONST MEMBER FUNCTION
```

An example,

```
void f(std::vector<int> const &v1, std::vector<int> & v2)
{
   std::cout << v1[0] << std::endl; //invokes const version    
   std::cout << v2[0] << std::endl; //invokes non-const version
}
```

Now when you write:

```
v[i] = 1;
```

If I don't assume `v` to be  `std::vector`, then it depends on the const-ness of the `v`. If `v` is const, then const-version will be invoked, else non-const version will be invoked (if it is available, else `v` will convert into const object and then const function will be invoked).

Comment: Re the last part, it technically depends on the assignment operator. An assignment operator *can* be `const`. However, in practice that's only used for proxy objects, e.g. for indexing of multi-dimensional array.

Comment: I had a misconception that the invocation depends on if the `v[1]` is a lvalue. Just tested it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49ac283a40cd85bd and yes it depends on const-ness of `v`, which compiler can easily observe.

Comment: @texasbruce: Note an important thing: if there is NO non-const version, then const version will be invoked, irrespective of const-ness of v, though if there is NO const version and only non-const version is there, you cannot invoke it on const object.

Comment: @Nawaz so if there is only const version, when we `v[i]=1` it will give errors right?

Comment: @texasbruce:Not necessarily. It depends on the implementation of `operator[]` of v, as well as `=` of the return type. But built-in types, it will result in error.

Comment: @texasbruce: Lets try **not** to memorize them, instead THINK. Only input your mind needs is that a non-const member function can be invoked on only non-const object, and const member function can be invoked on const object (as well as non-const object if there is no non-const version of the function).

Answer (score 1):

The non-`const` member function cannot be called on a `const` object.

Hence, in order to be practically useful, the rules have to be that it's called on a non-`const` object, and that conversely, the `const` member function is called on a `const` object.

And that's what the rules are.