# whats the purpose of a const "at()" and a non-const at()" in this code?

Tags: c++, constants

```
template<typename T>    
class vector {     
 vector();     
 vector(const vector& c);     
 vector(size_t num, const T& val = T());     
 ~vector();      
 T& operator[](size_t index);     
 const T& operator[](size_t index) const;     
 vector operator=(const vector& v);      
 T& at(size_t loc);     
 const T& at(size_t loc) const;      
 void pop_back();     
 void push_back(const T& val);      
 size_t size() const;     
};
```

Comment: Look at the question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438348/how-does-compiler-determine-which-function-to-use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It allows you to look up an item when the vector is const, or non-const.

For example:

```
const vector<int> x;
x.at(0); // Calls const version;

vector<int> y;
x.at(0); // Calls non-const version;
```

It's a very common C++ paradigm to overload a method based on `const`. In the example yo've posted the `operator[]` also has a const and non-const version, for the same reason.

Comment: thnx alot!!
and why there is three constructors?!

Comment: @user3036061 - because they do 3 different things! The first is the default construtor, which just constructs an empty vector. The second constructs the vector by copying the contents of another vector. The third constructs a vector by populating it with `num` copies of `val`.

Answer (score 1):

You can say you are overloading the `vector.at()` method. First one takes an implicit `Vector* this` parameter, but second one takes a `const Vector* this` parameter (beside the const reference return, note the `const` on the method signature). As consequence, first one will be called on const instances, and the second one on non-const instances.

Answer (score 0):

`T& at(size_t loc);` returns a reference to `T` and can work on a `vector<>` which was not declared as `const`.   `const T& at(size_t loc) const;` returns a `const` reference to `T` and is used when you have a `vector<>` which was declared as `const`.

Pretty constent, right?  The container preserves the meaning of `const`.